# Validate Django Choices with Accents in ModelForms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have this model in Django:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Student(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (('Graduación', 'Graduación'),
               ('Baja Temporal', 'Baja Temporal'),
               ('Expulsión', 'Expulsión'))
    persona = models.OneToOneField(Persona)
    enrollemente_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    prev_school = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    medical_notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    enrollement_date = models.DateField()
    egress_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    egress_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=CHOICES,
                                 blank=True, null=True)
    egress_comments = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.persona.get_full_name()
```

And I created this ModelForm:

```
class UnenrollForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student

        labels = {
            'egress_date': 'Fecha',
            'egress_reason': 'Razón de Baja',
            'egress_comments': 'Comentarios',
        }

        widgets = {
        'egress_comments': Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3}),
    }

    exclude = ['persona', 'enrollemente_code', 'prev_school',
               'medical_notes', 'enrollement_date']
```

When I call the unenrollform.is_valid() at my View, I get this warning:

```
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal '==': infix(10, lambda context, x, y: x.eval(context) == y.eval(context)),
```

And the egress_reason field is considered wrong.

Do you know any way to validate this? Or a turn around?

Comment: Which Python version (2.x or 3.x) are you using?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper It's Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the `CHOICES` array, your entries are supposed to be `(code, label)`. The code is what Django actually uses internally and in the DB, whereas the label is purely presentational.

Here, it would make sense for you to follow that convention. Among other things, this will make internationalizing your project easier down the road (if needed). Incidentally, it should also make your problem go away:

```
CHOICES = (('graduated', 'Graduación'),
           ('temporary', 'Baja Temporal'),
           ('expelled', 'Expulsión'))
```

Note that if you already have data in your DB, you're going to have to somehow migrate it.

---

Now, depending on which version of Python you're using, it's also a good idea to ensure your non-ASCII strings are declared as unicode (otherwise, you're leaving it up to Python to guess their encoding at runtime).

Specifically, in Python 2, you should do the following (in Python 3, you don't need to do anything):

```
CHOICES = (('graduated', u'Graduación'),
           ('temporary', u'Baja Temporal'),
           ('expelled', u'Expulsión'))
```

Also, make sure you to declare the encoding of your file. The first line should be:

```
#coding:utf-8
```

Note that this assumes that your file is encoded in `utf-8`, but that's a pretty safe assumption.

Comment: I think the only strictly necessary changes are declaring the text containing non-ascii characters as `u'Graduación'` and declaring the encoding of the file. There's nothing really wrong with using `'Expulsión'` as the code.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper On Django's side, sure, but then you open up a whole new can of worms. Those strings will be used by browsers, possibly API clients if Bulos decides to add an API, etc., and every single one of these clients will need to handle those strings properly. Considering there is 0 tangible benefit in using non-ASCII strings here, I'm sincerely doubtful it's worth the trouble.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @ThomasOrozco. It is better and easier to use strings without accents at the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am using python 2.7, and i resolved it adding an 'u' to the strings, for example

**u'Explicación'**

Applied to labels

```
labels = {
            'anio': _(u'Escriba el año'),
            'tarjetacirculacion': _(u'# de tarjeta de circulación'),
        }
```